# SWIFT - Handling array response body from HTTP request

Tags: ios, swift, codable

I recently created an Android APP in Java that retrieves listing data via PHP scripts and MySQL. Here is a sample of the data that is retrieved.

```
[
{
    "chapter_id": 1,
    "chapter_title": "Chapter 1: Awakening\u300aTo Find True Love\u300b",
    "media": [
        {
            "media_id": "992ea9eee0824d7e95503fc57f7c72b3",
            "media_title": "Episode 1",
            "media_description": "This lecture, is the \u201copening chapter\u201d of the ten lecture series of Unit 1 \u300aLove Lets Children Fly\u300b\r\n\r\nThere are no parents who don\u2019t love their children, but if don\u2019t know how to love, love will become hurt. Through Lao Wang's true story, the speaker explained that \"only say love is not enough, we must also know how to love\" in order to avoid the recurrence of family tragedy.\r\n\r\nEveryone is eager to have a golden key to happiness and love, so that our most beloved children can fly happily in the sky of love. But the question is where is the \"golden key to happiness and love\"?\r\n\r\nThis lecture will share 3 true touching stories of \u201clove lets children fly\u201d. Although the 3 protagonists come from different countries, indeed their parents have successfully mastered the golden key of Appreciation True Love, which let these 3 protagonists flying high with their invisible wings in the broad sky to chase their dreams.\r\n",
            "media_url": "992ea9eee0824d7e95503fc57f7c72b3",
            "media_url_alt": "f512a57f574647a2b747bb9452c096b3",
            "media_thumbnail": "992ea9eee0824d7e95503fc57f7c72b3",
            "view_count": 250,
            "like_count": 11,
            "favourite_count": 9,
            "media_type": "video",
            "created_date": "2020-12-05"
        },
        {
            "media_id": "eb9827ebabdc492fb496760013817497",
            "media_title": "Episode 1 Q&A",
            "media_description": "What should I do if my child procrastinates?\r\nDidn't attend class seriously?\r\nChildren love to play games and mobile phones?\r\nChildren react very slowly and do things very slowly. How to guide him?\r\nWhat to do if you have trouble concentrating?\r\nHow to let children take the initiative to write homework?\r\nWhat to do if the child is rebellious?",
            "media_url": "eb9827ebabdc492fb496760013817497",
            "media_url_alt": "ae481f86325b4d1fa1ff92777dded1f6",
            "media_thumbnail": "eb9827ebabdc492fb496760013817497",
            "view_count": 90,
            "like_count": 3,
            "favourite_count": 3,
            "media_type": "video",
            "created_date": "2020-12-05"
        }
    ]
},
{
    "chapter_id": 2,
    "chapter_title": "Chapter 2: Detoxification\u300aUnderstanding  Complaint Education\u300b",
    "media": [
        {
            "media_id": "f9f45733714c47088b5216ce8a956726",
            "media_title": "Episode 1",
            "media_description": "After listening to the lecture, I agree that appreciation is good, and I agree that appreciation is right, but when I want to practice it, I will naturally fall back to my original form! Many beginners ask: Why does this happen? This lecture will explain why this phenomenon is so hard to do, but so good to hear!",
            "media_url": "f9f45733714c47088b5216ce8a956726",
            "media_url_alt": "013c1bc866ef480884f52cfb74b64aaa",
            "media_thumbnail": "f9f45733714c47088b5216ce8a956726",
            "view_count": 28,
            "like_count": 2,
            "favourite_count": 0,
            "media_type": "video",
            "created_date": "2022-03-15"
        },
        {
            "media_id": "2d95873e89d54f8098b58e7de4825a61",
            "media_title": "Episode 1 Q & A",
            "media_description": "I believe that many audience members have found that their children have a negative and passive mindset towards everything, no matter how their parents guide them, they are still negative and passive, so how should we parents love and appreciate our children to be proactive? Of course, many children's first reaction to difficulties is negative, so how can we as parents guide our children to have the ability to react positively? This consultation lecture will answer the above major questions and make it easier for you to guide your children to become proactive and positive minded.",
            "media_url": "2d95873e89d54f8098b58e7de4825a61",
            "media_url_alt": "5af313d423c648a0bb30a28db51e039d",
            "media_thumbnail": "2d95873e89d54f8098b58e7de4825a61",
            "view_count": 5,
            "like_count": 1,
            "favourite_count": 1,
            "media_type": "video",
            "created_date": "2022-03-15"
        }
    ]
}
]
```

I am now creating the iOS version of this app. I am fairly new to Swift and I've hit a roadblock on how to read this data into the app. In the Java app, there are Lists of Chapter and Media objects that translate accordingly.

Here is the code in Swift that I have so far for this process. I created some structs for the chapter and media but I'm still not sure how it would fit in handling the response.

```
 struct Chapter: Codable {
    var chapter_id: String
    var chapter_title: String
    var media = [Media]()
    
    struct Media: Codable {
        var media_id: String
        var media_title: String
        var media_description: String
        var media_url: String
        var media_url_alt: String
        var media_thumbnail: String
        var view_count: Int
        var like_count: Int
        var favourite_count: Int
        var media_type: String
        var created_date: String
    }
 }

func retrieveVideoList(language: String) {
    let url = URL(string: baseURL + "retrieveVideoList.php")!
    
    var urlRequest = URLRequest(url: url)
    urlRequest.httpMethod = "POST"
    urlRequest.setValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    urlRequest.httpBody = "language=\(language)".data(using: .utf8)
    
    // Perform HTTP Request
    let session = URLSession.shared
    let task = session.dataTask(with: urlRequest) { (data, response, error) in

        // Check for Error
        if let error = error {
            print("Error took place \(error.localizedDescription)")
            return
        }
        
        guard let data = data else { return }
                
        let decoder = JSONDecoder()
        
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1) {
            do {
                let jsonData = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .mutableContainers) as! [Any]                    
                print(jsonData)
            } catch {
                print(error.localizedDescription)
            }
        }
    }
    task.resume()
}
```

This is the output of print(jsonData). I noticed that "media" in the sample above has become media as below.

```
[{
    "chapter_id" = 1;
    "chapter_title" = "Chapter 1: Awakening\U300aTo Find True Love\U300b";
    media =     (
                {
            "created_date" = "2020-12-05";
            "favourite_count" = 9;
            "like_count" = 11;
            "media_description" = "This lecture, is the \U201copening chapter\U201d of the ten lecture series of Unit 1 \U300aLove Lets Children Fly\U300b
\n
\nThere are no parents who don\U2019t love their children, but if don\U2019t know how to love, love will become hurt. Through Lao Wang's true story, the speaker explained that \"only say love is not enough, we must also know how to love\" in order to avoid the recurrence of family tragedy.
\n
\nEveryone is eager to have a golden key to happiness and love, so that our most beloved children can fly happily in the sky of love. But the question is where is the \"golden key to happiness and love\"?
\n
\nThis lecture will share 3 true touching stories of \U201clove lets children fly\U201d. Although the 3 protagonists come from different countries, indeed their parents have successfully mastered the golden key of Appreciation True Love, which let these 3 protagonists flying high with their invisible wings in the broad sky to chase their dreams.
\n";
            "media_id" = 992ea9eee0824d7e95503fc57f7c72b3;
            "media_thumbnail" = 992ea9eee0824d7e95503fc57f7c72b3;
            "media_title" = "Episode 1";
            "media_type" = video;
            "media_url" = 992ea9eee0824d7e95503fc57f7c72b3;
            "media_url_alt" = f512a57f574647a2b747bb9452c096b3;
            "view_count" = 250;
        },
                {
            "created_date" = "2020-12-05";
            "favourite_count" = 3;
            "like_count" = 3;
            "media_description" = "What should I do if my child procrastinates?
\nDidn't attend class seriously?
\nChildren love to play games and mobile phones?
\nChildren react very slowly and do things very slowly. How to guide him?
\nWhat to do if you have trouble concentrating?
\nHow to let children take the initiative to write homework?
\nWhat to do if the child is rebellious?";
            "media_id" = eb9827ebabdc492fb496760013817497;
            "media_thumbnail" = eb9827ebabdc492fb496760013817497;
            "media_title" = "Episode 1 Q&A";
            "media_type" = video;
            "media_url" = eb9827ebabdc492fb496760013817497;
            "media_url_alt" = ae481f86325b4d1fa1ff92777dded1f6;
            "view_count" = 90;
        }
    );
}, {
    "chapter_id" = 2;
    "chapter_title" = "Chapter 2: Detoxification\U300aUnderstanding  Complaint Education\U300b";
    media =     (
                {
            "created_date" = "2022-03-15";
            "favourite_count" = 0;
            "like_count" = 2;
            "media_description" = "After listening to the lecture, I agree that appreciation is good, and I agree that appreciation is right, but when I want to practice it, I will naturally fall back to my original form! Many beginners ask: Why does this happen? This lecture will explain why this phenomenon is so hard to do, but so good to hear!";
            "media_id" = f9f45733714c47088b5216ce8a956726;
            "media_thumbnail" = f9f45733714c47088b5216ce8a956726;
            "media_title" = "Episode 1";
            "media_type" = video;
            "media_url" = f9f45733714c47088b5216ce8a956726;
            "media_url_alt" = 013c1bc866ef480884f52cfb74b64aaa;
            "view_count" = 28;
        },
                {
            "created_date" = "2022-03-15";
            "favourite_count" = 1;
            "like_count" = 1;
            "media_description" = "I believe that many audience members have found that their children have a negative and passive mindset towards everything, no matter how their parents guide them, they are still negative and passive, so how should we parents love and appreciate our children to be proactive? Of course, many children's first reaction to difficulties is negative, so how can we as parents guide our children to have the ability to react positively? This consultation lecture will answer the above major questions and make it easier for you to guide your children to become proactive and positive minded.";
            "media_id" = 2d95873e89d54f8098b58e7de4825a61;
            "media_thumbnail" = 2d95873e89d54f8098b58e7de4825a61;
            "media_title" = "Episode 1 Q & A";
            "media_type" = video;
            "media_url" = 2d95873e89d54f8098b58e7de4825a61;
            "media_url_alt" = 5af313d423c648a0bb30a28db51e039d;
            "view_count" = 5;
        }
    );
}]
```

If someone could guide me in the right direction, I'd much appreciate it. Thank you.

Comment: You are printing a `Swift Array` (with as `[...]`), but with `Any`, you didn't specify the type, so it's a `NSDictionary`, that's the way they are printed with `description` following the OpenStepFormat. You never used your `Codable` sruct.

Comment: Unrelated but `print(error.localizedDescription)` should be `print(error)` as `localizedDescription` skips important information for developers.

Comment: @Larme Thank you for the reply. I am not sure how to integrate the struct into the http response which is why my code is as so.

Comment: Unrelated but `mutableContainers` is pointless in Swift. You can omit the parameter. And what is the delay (`asyncAfter`) for?

Comment: Paste e json into QuickType.io

Comment: @vadian I was following a tutorial on youtube about sending data with a delay while displaying a loading icon. I copied it from another code.

Comment: Use `JSONDecoder()` as pointed out in SH_Khan answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/74516901/1801544 As seeing also `.mutableContainers`, `JSONSerialization`, and `as! [Any]`, I'd suggest to see other tutorial, they seem either wrong, outdated (`Codable` is a "recent new feature"), or both.

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```
    let decoder = JSONDecoder()
    
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1) {
        do {
            let jsonData = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .mutableContainers) as! [Any]                    
            print(jsonData)
        } catch {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }
```

With

```
 do {
       let res = try JSONDecoder().decode([Chapter].self,data)
        print(res)
 }
 catch  {
    print(error)
 }
```